# Getting an interface from GetPropValue

Tags: delphi, rtti, getproperty

I want to dynamically get a property value from an object instance.
I was able to get the class properties, ordinal types and strings. The delphi source of the GetPropValue does not support tkInterface. Is there any way of getting the interface using the property info. BTW all the properties exposed are published properties.

for time being, i am using the TObject as the return type. GetPropValue returns the address of the object instance. I am typecasting that to TObject and returning the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to use [GetInterfaceProp()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/TypInfo.GetInterfaceProp) function. Usage is same as `GetPropValue()` but it returns an `IInterface` which you can "cast" to right type using ie [Supports()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.Supports).